# JSONP JQuery AJAX Not working with valid url

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm not able to get the JSONP data using $.ajax or $.getJSON, despite using a valid url (which works in the browser).

- url: http://www.itis.gov/ITISWebService/jsonservice/searchForAnyMatch?srchKey=dog&jsonp=?
  (This works in the browser)

From what I could surmise, this is what happens to the url when using JQuery:
- url: http://www.itis.gov/ITISWebService/jsonservice/searchForAnyMatch?srchKey=dog&callback=jQuery11100002686097053810954_1405836285524&_=1405836285525
    (This returns an empty result..and I've no idea why)

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: share your ajax code please?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems jQuery's cache busting messes up the result as the service doesn't handle unkown querystrings, like the one jQuery adds to avoid caching the resource.

You can just turn of cache busting and jQuery won't add the random string, and then it works fine

```
$.ajax({
    url      : 'http://www.itis.gov/ITISWebService/jsonservice/searchForAnyMatch?srchKey=dog&jsonp=?',
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    cache    : true
}).done(function(data)  {
    // ta-da
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Rq35/1/)